# Omitting "is" or "is to be" to avoid repetition

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure

In the last test there was an argumentative question. The question goes like:

> My aim is to be an engineer and my sister's aim is to be a doctor.
>
> Here, What has to be omitted?

I was asked to omit verbs to avoid repetition. I omitted "is to be" but my teacher said only "is" had to be omitted. Which is correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "what has to be omitted"? The sentence is fine as is, and if I *wanted* to omit something from it, it would be part of a verb phrase but *not* a verb. Are you sure you're being asked to omit a verb specifically?

Comment: Yes sir
I'm being asked to omit verbs to avoid repetition. It is the grammar question, which is called omission of verbs. I omitted"is to be" but my teacher said "is" only had to be omitted.

Comment: Could you give an example or two in your question? It may be clearer to write them on separate lines, once without the omission, and then again with the omission. Then we can clearly understand what asking about.

Comment: From reading your question, maybe you are thinking of "My aim is to be an engineer and my sister's aim is to be a doctor" --> "My aim is to be an engineer and my sister's is to be a doctor." I.e. the word "aim" was omitted.

Comment: Poor test question, then, if the desired answer was "... my sister's aim to be a doctor", because "my sister's aim[noun] to be" is pronounced the same as "my sisters aim[verb] to be", so in the real world it would be better to avoid that phrasing.

Answer (score 2):

No verbs can be omitted. Only the noun "aim" in the second clause can be omitted:

> My aim is to be an engineer and my sister's _____ is to be a doctor.

To remove any of the verbs either breaks the grammar or the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the question is about shortening the second part - "my sister's aim is to be a doctor". In this part, leaving out *is* or *to be* sounds very awkward. Leaving out *to be* could even be (offensively perhaps) understood as saying that my sister's aim is to *marry* a doctor.

While it does not meet the requirements of the question, the word "aim" could be left out and the sentence would be natural. If "aim" is omitted, then "is" could also be omitted, giving

> My aim is to be an engineer and my sister's to be a doctor.

While this is possible, in my view the original sentence is better.

Comment: What's wrong with "My aim is to be an engineer and my sister's **is** to be a doctor." To me, that would be clear as talking about my/my sister's **aims**, respectively. E.g. "My house is in the city, and yours is in the countryside." The topic of discussion is "house" so it need not be repeated. But it could be if you wish, or if it needs emphasis.

Comment: @Brandin, your suggestion is a perfectly good sentence with the correct meaning. However, OP specifically asked for a *verb* to be omitted, so I did not actually write it out when I mentioned the possibility in my 2nd paragraph.

Comment: Thank you so much for your considerate and professional answers.

Comment: I really appreciate all your answers.

Comment: It is from our new syllabus. There is a similar question like this one. It's also to omit. My hobby is collecting stamps and John's hobby is collecting CDs. I was in my full understanding in other questions like grass is eaten by grasshoppers and frogs are eaten by hawks. In the answer, we had to omit is eaten and are eaten. I'm hoping this text would be helpful for my questions. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: @baka Omission of repeated verbs sounds more natural in some cases than others. The sentence "Grass is eaten by grasshoppers and frogs by hawks" sounds natural to me, but  verb omission in the original example sounds strange.

Comment: If clarity is more important to you, you could employ the word "respectively", although this can make your statement more formal. For example: "Grass and frogs are eaten by grasshoppers and hawks, respectively."